# Typescript errors when importing a "not exported" type, even though it is exported

Tags: typescript, import, redux, module, export

I'm using Typescript, React & Redux (if relevant). My project structure:

```
/project
  /src
    /actions
      index.ts
      actions.ts
```

**index.ts**

```
import {
    Action,
} from "./actions";

export { Action }
```

I re-export `Actions` in `index.ts` so that other files (not under the `/actions` directory) can import the `Actions` type using `import { Action } from "./actions"`

**actions.ts**

```
// These are the general structures create each
// async action
type Request<T>  = { request: T }
type Response<T> = { response: T }
type Err         = { error: string }

// Alias common types for requests & responses
type EmptyRequest = Request<null>
type ValueRequest = Request<{ value: number }>

export type Action
    // UI Actions
    = ({ type: "INCREMENT_COUNTER", delta: number })
    | ({ type: "RESET_COUNTER" })
    // Aync Actions
    | ({ type: "SAVE_COUNT_REQUEST" } & ValueRequest)
    | ({ type: "SAVE_COUNT_SUCCESS" } & Response<{}>)
    | ({ type: "SAVE_COUNT_FAILURE" } & Err)
```

I get this error:

```
Type error: Module '"<snipped path>"' has no exported member 'Action'.
TS2305
```

When I try to import `Action` *anywhere*.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16):

**Typescript 3.8 introduces new syntax for type-only imports and exports**:

```
import type T from './module';
import type { A, B } from './module';
import type * as Types from './module';

export type { T };
export type { T } from './module';
```

This enables exporting types via `index.ts` (module's public API) files as we would do with other exported members. **Just add `type` keyword in front of destructured types/interfaces**:

```
export type { Actions } from './actions';
```

---

In the earlier versions of Typescript (before 3.8) to make it work, it's necessary to reexport imported types:
*(looks pretty ugly, but does the job)*

```
import { Actions as _Actions } from "./actions";
export type Actions = Actions;
```

References:
 - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-8-beta
 - https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/35200

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use named import and not default import when importing actions:

```
// index.ts
import { Actions } from './actions';
export { Actions }
// elsewhere
import { Actions } from './path/to/src/action';
```

Or, use default export in both index and elsewhere:

```
// index.ts
import { Actions } from './actions';
export default Action;
// elsewhere
import Actions from './path/to/src/action';
```